# Ionic 3 - App stuck on splashscreen. Starts running once I make a change and refreshes while emulating (iOS)

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

Have an Ionic 3 app, that gets stuck on splash screen when I'm emulating on iOS. Funny thing, if I add a space to a ts file, it refreshes and starts working.

[image]

This is messing up my E2E testing with Appium, so I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea of what might be causing this behaviour.

I'm leaving here all package.json dependencies, in case that helps:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/common": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/aes-256": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/battery-status": "^4.9.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^4.10.1",
"@ionic-native/device": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/dialogs": "^4.9.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.9.0",
"@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.10.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.10.0",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/http": "^4.10.0",
"@ionic-native/insomnia": "^4.9.2",
"@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.15.0",
"@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.9.0",
"@ionic-native/media": "^4.9.0",
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/power-management": "^4.9.2",
"@ionic-native/pro": "^4.9.2",
"@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
"@ionic/pro": "^2.0.3",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
"awesome": "0.0.7",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
"cordova-ios": "5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^1.11.1",
"cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-background-upload": "^1.0.12",
"cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
"cordova-plugin-battery-status": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
"cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.1",
"cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.3.1",
"cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-ios-disableshaketoedit": "^1.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-itunesfilesharing": "0.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
"cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-powermanagement-orig": "^1.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic-native-datepicker": "^1.0.5",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"ios-sim": "^8.0.2",
"jquery": "3.3.1",
"jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
"ngx-dropdown-list": "^1.1.1",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.3",
"ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
"ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
"node-sass": "4.9.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.3",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^6.4.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.4.2",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.4.2",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^6.4.0",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^6.4.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.4.0",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.4.0",
    "appium": "^1.18.1",
    "appium-doctor": "^1.15.3",
    "chromedriver": "^84.0.1",
    "ionic-mocks": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^4.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "wdio-appium-service": "^0.2.3",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.3",
    "wdio-jasmine-framework": "^0.3.8",
    "wdio-mochawesome-reporter": "^4.0.0",
    "wdio-spec-reporter": "^0.1.5",
    "webdriverio": "^6.4.2",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  },
```

---

BTW, already tried the following:

- Removing platform and building again

  ```
   ionic cordova platform rm ios
   ionic cordova platform add ios@5.0.0
   ionic cordova emulate ios -lc --target iPad--6th-generation-
  ```
- When preparing/building I have a different issue:

  ```
   ionic-app-script task: "build" 
   Error: Failed to transpile program 
   at new BuildError ([...]/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, basically there was a conflict  between Ionic and Appium dependencies.

Spent a few hours trying to crack that, but opted for moving appium implementation along with E2E tests to a separate folder.

Answer (score -1):

Clean and rebuild

```
ionic clean
ionic build
```

Comment: There's no clean command. Already tried removing the platform and adding it from scratch.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it